# Running Garmin ANT Agent

Tags: 12.10, wine

Im looking for the best way to install and run Garmin ANT Agent. Ive looked around but there isnt many option. I am running Xubuntu 12.10 and have a Forerunner 910 XT watch. Ive tried using Wine to run it but the drop down menu doesnt work correctly as I cant select the option to Pair a device as the drop down menu closes.

I looked at using Virtual Machine but wasnt sure about how to set it up correctly I looked at there guide but it didnt help much. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running the Garmin ANT Agent in a Windows XP Virtual Machine under Virtual Box.
Note that you can't use the standard Virtual Box installation as that doesn't include USB support - you need an extension pack, which you can download: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 4):

There is a project on GitHub called [Garmin-Forerunner-610-Extractor](https://github.com/Tigge/Garmin-Forerunner-610-Extractor). The name confuses a little bit, but at the moment the following Ant-devices are supported:

- Garmin Forerunner 60
- Garmin Forerunner 405CX
- Garmin Forerunner 310XT
- Garmin Forerunner 610
- Garmin Forerunner 910XT
- Garmin FR70
- Garmin Swim

There is no specific ubuntu-package at the moment, but the program consists of a simple Python script.